# VUE3 dataLabels stacked column apex chart

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, apexcharts

I want show only top total datalabels but is dublicate label

[image]

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    offsetY: -20,
    style: {
      fontSize: "12px",
      colors: ["#304758"],
    },

    formatter: function (value, { seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
      return w.globals.stackedSeriesTotals[dataPointIndex];

    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `formatter` I come up with, should work for any number of series

```
formatter: function (value, { seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
  let numberOfSeries = w.config.series.length - 1
  if(seriesIndex == numberOfSeries){
    return w.globals.stackedSeriesTotals[dataPointIndex];
  } else if (seriesIndex<numberOfSeries){
    let sum = 0
    while (seriesIndex < numberOfSeries) {
      seriesIndex++;
      sum+= w.config.series[seriesIndex].data[dataPointIndex] || 0
    }
    if (sum === 0) return w.globals.stackedSeriesTotals[dataPointIndex];
  }
},
```

Comment: This code not working for me don't show anything but 
f(seriesIndex !== numberOfSeries){
    return w.globals.stackedSeriesTotals[dataPointIndex];
  } 
show the same duplicate

Comment: https://codepen.io/Gahzee/pen/MWQWOKY